# Difficulty with proof of Spectral Theorem

Tags: linear-algebra, eigenvalues-eigenvectors, proof-explanation

I recently found a proof of the spectral theorem for symmetric matrices that I had not seen before [here](http://www.math.lsa.umich.edu/~speyer/417/SpectralTheorem.pdf). I am having difficulty understanding their proof of what they call "Lucky Fact 2" which shows that for a symmetric matrix the algebraic multiplicity of an eigenvalue is equal to its geometric multiplicity. I follow the proof of this until the very last line wherein the author writes.

> ...which should have been listed when we found the $v_{i}$

Which is meant to imply that $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ \mathbf{u}\end{pmatrix}$ could not be an eigenvector of $A$ however I do not see why this is the case as $\begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 0 \\ \mathbf{u}\end{pmatrix}$ could simply equal $v_{1}$ or $v_{2}$ and be an eigenvector of $A$ with no issue.

Could someone explain to me why this is the case?

Comment: The $v_i$ are living in the upper part where you have zeroes here. You've changed coordinates so that the first $r$ coordinates of the vector correspond to the vectors $v_1,\dots,v_r$.

Comment: @TedShifrin Sorry I don't understand what you are referring to when you say that $v_{i}$ live in the upper part. Which vector have we changed the coordinates of so that they correspond to $v_{1}, ..., v_{r}$?

Comment: You've changed basis using the matrix $S$. We're talking about the matrix $SAS^{-1}$ here.

Comment: @TedShifrin So if I understand correctly - As $SAS^{-1}$ represents the action of the matrix $A$ defined under the transformation $S$ then because $v_{1}$ and $v_{2}$ are the first two elements and $\textbf{u}'= \begin{pmatrix}0 , 0 , \textbf{u} \end{pmatrix}^{T}$ has zeroes as its first two elements it means that it cannot be a linear combination of either $v_{1}$ or $v_{2}$ and therefore can be neither as $v_{i}$ formed an ON basis of $\mathbb{R}^{n}$ and no combination or $v_{r+1}$ to $v_{n}$ can form $v_{1}$ to $v_{r}$?

Comment: Correct, because $v_1,\dots,v_r,v_{r+1},\dots,v_n$ is a basis, after all.

Comment: @TedShifrin Thanks, that's a nifty proof.